# How to put image inside a button in JS or how to disabled a image button when condition is meet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have this code in my JQgrid to create a button inside a grid

```
afterInsertRow: function (rowid) {
          var obj = jQuery("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").getRowData(rowid);
          var FADTLSID = obj.FitaAssignDtlID;
          if (FADTLSID !== undefined) {
              if (FADTLSID !== "") {
                  var btnApprove = "<img  alt='' src='../../Content/Images/newimages/check.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;'  style ='width: 90px' id='btnApprove" + rowid + "' onclick='clickmeapproved(" + rowid + " )' />"
                  var btnDisApprove = "<img  alt='' src='../../Content/Images/newimages/delete.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;' style ='width: 90px' id='btnApprove" + rowid + "' onclick='clickmedisapproved(" + rowid + " )' />"
                  jQuery("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").setRowData(rowid, { FitaCorForApproval: btnApprove });
                  jQuery("#FiTATimeCorrectionV2List").setRowData(rowid, { FitaCorForDisApproval: btnDisApprove });
                  var temp = obj.FitaStatus;                        
                  if (temp == "Approved") {
                      $("#btnApprove" + rowid).attr("disabled", true);                         
                      $("#btnDisApprove" + rowid).attr("disabled", true);
                  } else {
                      $("#btnApprove" + rowid).attr("disabled", false);
                      $("#btnDisApprove" + rowid).attr("disabled", false);
                  }
              }
          }
      },
```

That kind of code is in image format however the code for disable is not working if I change to `<input type = 'button'` the code is working and the image disappear. I just want to create a image button which if a condition has been meet the image button is disabled. What I want is after the data loaded the image button/s will be `disabled` or `enabled` if the condition is meet. As code above when the `Status` is `Approved` or `Disapproved` I want to disabled all the image button/s.

Comment: Is it possible for you to set the code up in something like https://jsfiddle.net/ ? This will make it easier for other to troubleshoot.

Comment: @kcdragon as sample code above after the grid loaded when the status is `Approved` the `image type button` will be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

```js
$("button:eq(0)").attr("disabled", false);
$("button:eq(1)").attr("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>1. button</button>
<button>2. button</button>
```

Comment: I tried earlier the code .prop but it says .prop is not a function. I don't know why. But so far I research some links are using .prop